# Запятая внутри придаточного предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

"Через несколько часов, когда снег прекратился, и показалась жёлтая луна, я добрался до ночлега".
Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Через несколько часов, **когда снег прекратился и показалась жёлтая луна**, я добрался до ночлега.*

1. В данном предложении однородные придаточные, соединенные союзом И, занимают **уточняющую позицию** по отношению **к обстоятельству времени** «через несколько часов». Такая структура СПП встречается довольно часто, например: *Весной, **когда сходит снег и земля прогревается,** в лесистых Черных горах расцветают подснежники.* [Герман Садулаев. Шалинский рейд (2009) // «Знамя», 2010]
2. Наличие обстоятельства времени  **не влияет**  на постановку знаков препинания, сравнить: ***Когда снег прекратился и показалась жёлтая луна**, я добрался до ночлега.*
3. Варианты в толковании СПП с однородными придаточными (с постановкой или отсутствием запятой перед союзом И) возможны только в том случае, если **на первом месте находится главная часть,** например: Хаджи-Мурат так задумался, что не заметил, как нагнул кувшин, и вода лилась из него (Л. Т.)
   Розенталь: п.3 (примечание) https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139

Answer (score 4):

Запятая перед союзом ***и*** не нужна:

*Через несколько часов, когда снег прекратился и показалась жёлтая луна, я добрался до ночлега.*

Два придаточных предложения (***снег прекратился***, ***луна показалась***) относятся к одному главному (***я добрался***) и являются однородными.

[**§ 35. Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении с несколькими придаточными**](https://old-rozental.online/punctuatio.php?sid=139) (Розенталь)

> 3. Между однородными придаточными частями сложноподчиненного предложения, связанными неповторяющимися союзами (соединительными или разделительными), **запятая не ставится**: *Отец мой говорил, что он не видывал таких хлебов **и** что нынешний год урожай отличный* (Акс.).

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна. У них общее слово "когда". В таких случаях запятые не ставят.

Comment: Ответ верный, но объяснение некорректное. 1. Запятая не ставится при наличии общего «слова» в сложносочиненных предложениях (ССП), а здесь сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП).  2. Но даже в СПП союз «когда» нельзя считать общим элементом, так как  
постановка запятой не связана с наличием или отсутствием второго подчинительного союза (в данном случае он просто опускается). В действительности однородные придаточные в теме СПП объединяет общее главное предложение.